# Google Spreadsheets: number becomes date after SPLIT

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this text in A1: `18.03 x 13.76 x 1.48 cm`

Then I have this formula: `=SPLIT(A1;"x")`

Problem is that the output is set with a DATE format.
I mean that `18.8` becomes `18/03/2021` instead of `18.8`.

I need the output to have an **number** format instead of **date**.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: See if the specific technique I showed [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149315/247436) helps. Untested on your specific data though.

Comment: This behavior may be specific to your locale. Can you share a link to the sheet (or to a copy of it) or at least to a sheet with that one piece of raw data and the SPLIT of it not working? If we can access a sheet where it's happening, I guarantee, I or someone else here can help you address the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1;"\.";",");"x")
```

[image]

Or even

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1;"\.";",");" x")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=arrayformula(to_text(split(A1;"x")))
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SPLIT(A1; "x"); "@"))
```

or use internal formatting and set it to Number